# Setting line-height on a jsTree?

Tags: css, jstree

I'm using jstree to create a multi-level tree, and I want to be able to set a larger line-height than you usually see, so that I can have some large headings.  (If I set the font larger, the lines simply overlap.)

I've tried setting the line-height CSS property on the li and a elements, but neither have an effect; jstree seems to be programmatically overriding those values.  (I even tried using jQuery to re-set those values after the tree is created, but that didn't help.)

To make things more complicated I would like to have different levels have different spacing, so that the top levels can be larger than the deeper levels.

I've tried the theme plugin but I can't find anything to control line height.

Thanks...

Comment: Can we get a fiddle or screen-shot?

Comment: The complete working code is here: [http://www.nicholaschase.com/jstree/test.html].  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it help to increase the height of the element?

```
.jstree-leaf {
 font-size: 37px;
 height: 50px;
}

.jstree-leaf a.jstree-hovered {
 height: 50px;
}

.jstree-leaf a.jstree-clicked {
 height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: That was the clue that I needed, thank you!  Here's the full answer:

Comment: OK, I took too long to edit it, so here it is:

You also need to set .jstree-closed and set .jstree-open to "auto".  I've put together the whole sample (including having different sizes for different levels) here: [link]http://www.nicholaschase.com/jstree/test.html.  Thanks!

Comment: @NickChase It would be helpful if you post your solution as an answer here.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, this worked nicely for me. It won't give you super-large heading-size, but it increases the size perfectly for my liking.

Setup my tree with `variant: large`

```
//jstree config
$("#tree").jstree({
  "core" : {
    "themes" : {
      "variant" : "large"
    }
  }
  // ...
});
```

and then also change the font-size for all nodes:

```
/* CSS */    
.jstree-node {
    font-size: 13pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On its own, MMeah's solution did not work for me. Combining this with the code [here](https://code.google.com/p/jstree/issues/detail?id=670) and changing the height to `auto` worked for me. See full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24746827/1943).

```
.jstree-default a { 
    white-space:normal !important; height: auto; 
}
.jstree-anchor {
    height: auto !important;
}
.jstree-default li > ins { 
    vertical-align:top; 
}
.jstree-leaf {
    height: auto;
}
.jstree-leaf a{
    height: auto !important;
}
```