# How do I get a jstree node to display long, possibly multiline content?

Tags: css, jstree

When using the [jsTree plugin](http://www.jstree.com/), I need to have a node which displays its full content. Right now, the nodes only display approximately one line of text each. How can I get the nodes in a jsTree to display all of the text in the node without truncating the node's content?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following CSS code will do the trick:

```
.jstree-default a { 
    white-space:normal !important; height: auto; 
}
.jstree-anchor {
    height: auto !important;
}
.jstree-default li > ins { 
    vertical-align:top; 
}
.jstree-leaf {
    height: auto;
}
.jstree-leaf a{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

This is a modification of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163694/setting-line-height-on-a-jstree) (height changed to `auto`) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/jstree/issues/detail?id=670), neither of which worked for me on their own.

Comment: You saved a life today