# How to assign width for <li> tag in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jstree

I am new to jstree, and i have integrated it in my project. below is my code.

```
<div id="leaf" style"width:50px">
    <ul>
        <li>This is the first jstree leaf for testing</li> 
        <li>this is the second jstree leaf</li>
        <li>this is third</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want the li's not to overlap each other, because my div width is 50px only, i know it is the CSS work, but i cant find the class.

Comment: see this post it may help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163694/setting-line-height-on-a-jstree

Comment: did you finally find an answer for your question? If you did, please close the question accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inline style which will override external styles if any. Use min-width property, this will adjust your div based on its list items length.

```
<body>
<div id="leaf" style="min-width:50px">
    <ul>
        <li>This is the first jstree leaf for testing</li> 
        <li>this is the second jstree leaf</li>
       <li>this is third</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Check Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=GhIN00JQsr

Answer (score 1):

this is not a proper way to call css `<div id="leaf" style"width:50px">`
you missed the `=` sign you need to change that like `<div id="leaf" style="width:50px">`

Answer (score 0):

I think the classname you are looking for is `jstree-leaf`. You could try increasing the width of that class:

```
.jstree-leaf {
  width: 100px;
}
```

[image: jstree code view]

Also note that you are missing and `=` in the style attribute of your leaf `<div>`:

```
<div id="leaf" style="width:50px">
```