# How could I turn an interactive tree into a touch friendly interface?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jstree

I am currently making use of [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) to show certain (list) items. How could I make it possible to make such interface to work on a device making use of touch capability?

The problem I am having is that the `<li>`'s are way too small to tap on for touch capability purpose. I tried editing the height of my `<li>`'s but that seems to break the tree:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.jstree.defaults.core.themes.variant = "large";
  // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
  $('#jstree').jstree({
    "plugins": ["wholerow"]
  });
  // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
  $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function(e, data) {
    console.log(data.selected);
  });
  // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
    $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
    $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
  });
});
```

```css
#jstree > ul > li {
  /* height: 50px ; */  /* <-- Not workoing */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
  <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
  <ul>
    <li>Root node 1
      <ul>
        <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
        <li data-jstree='{"icon":"//jstree.com/tree.png"}'>Child node 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Root node 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button>demo button</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf63uxpy/)

Would anyone happen to know how the appearance of a jsTree could be edit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34000229/2060966

Comment: I know about the usage of a "large variant", but this is not what I am looking for unfortunately. @marsze

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6jap4n79/ try setting the height to the `a` and `div` inside `li`, instead of the `li` directly. If you inspect the element, it's the same thing JStree does

Comment: And what about those icons? (they seem to not line up with the text, I tried changing [the code](https://jsfiddle.net/c1qtvfjn/) but it does not get it) Seems close to what I would require related to my example given above.